# How to make object accessible to rest of class

Tags: c++, class

I need to create a class that can open a file and write to it, but am having a lot of trouble. I have searched and found answers that should have helped me, but I haven't been able to implement them. I can create the file but am unable to access it in main.
Say I have a class:

```
class Log{
  public:
  Log(string name){
     ofstream log(name);

  void Entry(string message){
       file << message << endl;
```

and I want to be able to print to this file created in the constructor from main using the Entry function.

```
int main(){
Log log("LogFile.txt);
log.Entry("message");
}
```

Of course, my fstream file isn't within the scope of Entry. How can I access it? I tried using a pointer and ended up with a memory leak crash; I am very rusty right now. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix your problem you need to use an instance variable in your class.

So your class would be:

```
class Log{
  ofstream log;
  public:
  Log(string name){
     log.open(name);

  void Entry(string message){
       file << message << endl;
```

Hope this helps.